# Android Studio Animation has the Wrong Number of Frames

Tags: java, android

I managed to play an animation sequence using `AnimationDrawable` object. However, I noticed some strange behavior, which results in the animation looping more than once even when I tell it to play once using `setOneShot()`=true. My goal is to be able to play an animation when a signal is received.

Anyways, every time I get a signal I add some frames to the `AnimationDrawable` in the createAnimation function. After noticing some animations playing more than once, I printed out the number of frames with `getNumberOfFrames()` and saw that AnimationDrawables I added the same number of frames to displayed different numbers of frames eg

```
System.out: start animation, end frame index is 270
System.out: Number of frames to play: 693

System.out: start animation, end frame index is 270
System.out: Number of frames to play: 1242
```

What would explain this? I've included the relevant functions below.

```
void createAnimation(AnimationDrawable animation, int endPixelIdx){
    int endFrameIdx;
    endFrameIdx = Math.min(endFrameIdx, 270);
    print("start animation, end frame index is " + endFrameIdx);
    for (int i = 0; i < endFrameIdx; i++) {
        animation.addFrame(artArr[i], 1); // adding drawables stored in memory
    }
} 

void playAnimationOnce(int stopFrameIdx){ // called from inside Handler in OnCreate()
    Drawable currentFrame = animation.getCurrent();
    if (currentFrame == prevFrame){ // we know an animation is over when frames don't change
        animation.stop(); // reset the animation
        createAnimation(animation, stopFrameIdx);
        imageanim.setImageDrawable(animation);
        animation.setOneShot(true);
        animation.start();
        System.out.println("Number of frames to play: " + animation.getNumberOfFrames());
    } 
    prevFrame = currentFrame;
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Handler handler=new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // upadte textView here
//                print("set dist text view text");
                distTextView.setText(intDistance + " Inches");
                int pixel = (int) (intDistance / inchPerPixel);
                playAnimationOnce(pixel);
                handler.postDelayed(this,500); // set time here to refresh textView
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to instantiate a new AnimationdDrawable() to remove the frames. It seems the frame count does not reset on `stop()`.